# CentOS kickstart - force kernel version

Tags: centos, redhat, kickstart

I'd like to kickstart some servers using a specific kernel version (slightly downrev) but can't figure out the correct syntax in the kickstart file. I've tried specifying this in the "%packages" section with both a minus-prefixed kernel package (to remove it) and an unprefixed entry but I get a multilib error message.

From kickstart file:

```
%packages --nobase
-kernel-2.6.32-504.23.4.el6.x86_64
kernel-2.6.32-504.16.2.el6.x86_64
...other packages...
```

Error message:

```
Protected multilib versions:
kernel-2.6.32-504.23.4.el6.x86_64 != kernel-2.6.32-504.16.2.el6.x86_64
```

Thanks!

Comment: What about fixing this in %post ?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Petter, downgrading the kernel in the %post section works:

```
%post
rpm -ivh --oldpackage http://my.repo.server/centos/6.6/updates/x86_64/Packages/kernel-2.6.32-504.16.2.el6.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ivh --oldpackage http://my.repo.server/centos/6.6/updates/x86_64/Packages/kernel-firmware-2.6.32-504.16.2.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is correct:

`%packages
kernel-2.6.32-504.16.2.el6.x86_64`

Will normally installed the specific package and its dependencies, if any.

Multilib error normally indicates a problem with interaction between 32 and 64 libraries, but in my experience, it can also indicate unsolvable conflicts between core packages.

A recommendation is to get a system in this state, then extract the full list of packages with `rpm -qa | sed 's/.rpm//'`, then paste them in the kickstart `%post` section.